# Laravel - How to save binary from Guzzle

Tags: php, laravel, guzzle

I need help, I make the request for a file using the following code:

```
$client = new Client(['verify' => false]);

$response = $client->request('GET', 'https://url', [
    'headers' => [
        'Authorization' => 'Bearer token'
    ]
]);

$mime = $response->getHeader('Content-Type');
$binary = $response->getBody();
```

The answer I receive is the following:

```
Content-Type: image/jpeg or other appropriate media type
Content-Length: content-size

binary-media-data
```

My question is: How to store this file? I could not find anything on the internet...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [Storage facade](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/filesystem#storing-files) to create a new file.

```
Storage::put('file.jpg', $binary)
```

If the Mime Type can change then get the file and then use PutFile:

```
use Illuminate\Http\File;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

$client = new Client(['verify' => false]);

$tmpfile = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(),'dl');

$response = $client->request('GET', $url, [
    'headers' => [
        'Authorization' => 'Bearer token'
    ],
    'sink' => $tmpfile
]);

$filename = Storage::putFile('dir_within_storage', new File($tmpfile));
```

If the file name is always reliable and you're not worried about duplicates then you can just uze Guzzle to put it directly:

```
$client = new Client(['verify' => false]);

$filePath = basename($url);

$response = $client->request('GET', $url, [
    'headers' => [
        'Authorization' => 'Bearer token'
    ],
    'sink' => storage_path('dir_within_storage/'.$filePath)
]);
```

Comment: When you say "didn't work", what error did you receive? And what steps did you try to resolve it?

Comment: didn’t get any error, it saves “the file” but it has no content, I am away from my computer right now, but in some minutes I’ll try this:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36771849/guzzle-get-file-and-forward-it

Comment: That question is designed to stream the file to a user as a download via their browser. Laravel has built-in features for this. Your original question was about downloading a file from the web to your server.

Comment: Have added two more methods to get the file with.

Comment: Any thoughts @CaioKawasaki ?